# Get P4 vars in Java code

Tags: java, perforce

I am using following commands in command lines to set the environment variable

```
p4 set p4user = userName;
p4 set p4passwd = password;
p4 set p4client = clientname;
```

I want to get these already set environment variable into java code i have written for creating new changelist

```
IServer server = ServerFactory.getServer(serverUrl, null);
server.connect();

server.setUserName(userName);
server.login(passwordObtained);
client = server.getClient(clientName);

System.out.println(client);

server.setCurrentClient(client);
changeListImpl = new Changelist(IChangelist.UNKNOWN, client.getName(),userName, ChangelistStatus.NEW, new Date(),"New ChangeList", false , (Server) server);
changelist = client.createChangelist(changeListImpl);
```

I tried `system.getenv()` but there is no luck probably `system.getenv()` gets environment variable set in environment setting. is there any way to get these environment variable into java code. those `changelist` i am creating using already available `p4javaxxxx.jar` file. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using Windows / OS X, cause p4 vars can't be set on Linux/Unix (In Linux / Unix they **are** env vars).

In Windows those variables are stored in the registry, and in OS X they are stored in OS X system settings (according to ['p4 set' documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_set.html)).

So, you'll need to get them from there...